# In sklearn is there a way to test the confidence of a prediction made my a DecisionTreeClassifier Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am succesfully using the sklearn library in python and really enjoying it.

I am able to create and fit a model of the DecisionTreeClassifierType with the following code:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
```

I can then use the model to predict the class of new inputs like so:

```
clf.predict([[20, 50, 10]])
```

The above line will return a 0 or a 1 depending on which class the model predicts this data will have.I was wondering if there is some way to get the confidence/probability the model has for a prediction?

So if it predicts the classification for the input to be 1, the probabiliy/confidence would be a decimal like 0.8 or a percent like 80%. Any ideas on if this is compatible/possible with sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done in [`sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba):

> Predict class probabilities of the input samples X.
>   The predicted class probability is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.